# Destructure Array and assign to property object in one line

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have these Javascript lines :

```
const record = {};
const parts = ['deviceId-abc', 'messagesId-def'];

record.deviceId = parts[0];
record.messageId = parts[1];
```

I have a linter error **prefer-destructuring** on the last two lines but I am not sure how I can both destructure an array and assign the value to an object property.

thanks,

Comment: See https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1791

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can destructure into your properties

```
const record = {};
const parts = ['deviceId-abc', 'messagesId-def'];

[record.deviceId, record.messageId] = parts;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could destructure an array and take the properties as target.

```js
const
    record = {},
    parts = ['deviceId-abc', 'messagesId-def'];

[record.deviceId, record.messageId] = parts;

console.log(record);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally do this:

```
const [deviceId, messageId] = ['deviceId-abc', 'messagesId-def'];
const record = { deviceId, messageId };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
const record = {};
const [parts,message]=['deviceId-abc', 'messagesId-def'];

record.deviceId = parts
record.messageId = message
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the array-like this

```js
const record = {};
const parts = ['deviceId-abc', 'messagesId-def'];

[record.deviceId,record.messageId]=parts;

console.log(record);
```